# How do i make the code to work and use a image when clicked to trigger a function?

Tags: python, pygame

i need a way when i enter to the second window, or the window with the image, it shows 3 images of burgers but i cant find a way to click on a image and trigger a function which allows me to ask if they want other things in the menu.

- [restaurant.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keqTO.jpg)
- [Hamburger.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEIrd.png)
- [Chicken.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrvX4.png)
- [tofu.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGg7e.png)
- [cheeseburger.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1ozq.png)

the images for the program are here

```
# Imports
import pygame
from threading import Timer

# start the game
pygame.init()

w, h = 200, 300

# making the windows
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
window2 = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
window3 = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
# set up the games name
pygame.display.set_caption("Ordering Simulator")

# Variables
pyX = 1280
pyY = 720
nextWindow = 0
# sprites
beefSprite = pygame.image.load("Hamburger.png").convert_alpha()
beefSprite.convert()
rectBeef = beefSprite.get_rect()
rectBeef.center = w // 2, h // 2
# Set up the text
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 64)
font2 = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
# Text
text = font.render("Welcome to Cesar's ordering sim", True, black, white)
text2 = font2.render("What would you like? We have beef, chicken and tofu sandwich.", True, white, black)
text3 = font2.render("So you have chosen.", True, white, black)
# icon
icon = pygame.image.load("cheeseburger.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
# setup text pt2
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect2 = text2.get_rect()
textRect3 = text3.get_rect()
textRect.center = (pyX // 2, pyY // 2)
textRect2.midtop = (pyX // 2, pyY - 600)
textRect3.midtop = (pyX // 2, pyY - 600)
# add a background
bg = pygame.image.load("restaurant.jpg")
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (1280, 720))


# define the background and the selection menu
def image():
    window2.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    window2.blit(beefSprite, (200, 300))
    window2.blit(text2, textRect2)


def selection1():
    window3.blit(text3, textRect3)


# timer setup
timer = Timer(3.0, image)
timerLoop = 0

# loop for game window
running = True
running2 = True
running3 = True
while running:
    window.blit(text, textRect)
    if timerLoop == 0:
        timer.start()
        timerLoop = timerLoop + 1
        nextWindow = nextWindow + 1
    else:
        running2 = True
        running = False

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            running2 = False
            running3 = False
    pygame.display.update()

# Second screen which starts the game
while running2:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            running2 = False
            running3 = False
        if nextWindow == 1:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if beefSprite.get_rect().collidepoint(mousePos):
                    selection1()
                    nextWindow = nextWindow + 1
        else:
            running = False
            running2 = False
            running3 = True
pygame.display.update()

# third screen
while running3:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running3 = False
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: if event is `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` then you can use `event.pos` instead of `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. Maybe you use wrong values.

Comment: you have wrong indentations - you have two `pygame.display.update()` outside while-loop. And I don't see where you run `image()` - so you don't display image in `window2`

Comment: as I know PyGame can display only one window - new window replace previous window - so making three windows makes no sense. You should create only `window` and use it in all code. And if you want to display three windows at the same time then you have to use some GUI framework - `tkinter`, `PyQt`,etc. - or you would have to run every PyGame window in separate thread. Current code doesn't do it (but you import `threading`) so we can't run it and see three windows.

Comment: and if you want to display three different "pages" in one window then you could draw every "page" on separated `Surface()` and only replace these surfaces in single window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two problems with Hamburger image

**First:**

You have image in `beefSprite` and at start you set position in `rectBeef`

```
rectBeef = beefSprite.get_rect()
rectBeef.center = w // 2, h // 2
```

but later you compare mouse position with `beefSprite.get_rect()`

```
if beefSprite.get_rect().collidepoint(mousePos):
```

which always gives `(x,y) = (0,0)` - so you compare with wrong rectangle.

You should use `rectBeef` instead of `beefSprite.get_rect()`

```
if rectBeef.collidepoint(mousePos):
```

**Second:**

You display image using position `(200, 300)`

```
window2.blit(beefSprite, (200, 300))
```

but you compare mouse position with `rectBeef` which may have different position

You should again use `rectBeef`

```
window2.blit(beefSprite, rectBeef)
```

And position `(200, 300)` you should set in `rectBeef` at start

```
rectBeef.lefttop = (200, 300)
```

or you could keep previous position

```
rectBeef.center = w // 2, h // 2
```

---

Other problem is `Timer` and `timerLoop`

`Timer` wait 3 seconds to run `image` but meanwhile code runs `running = False` so it moves from `while running` to `while running2` - so you can still see first screen but code may already run second loop and check `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`. You should set `running = False` inside `image()` which is executed after 3 seconds.

Or maybe you should rather use `pygame.timer` to check current time and exit first loop after 3 seconds, and next display images and run second loop

---

Other "problem" is `window`, `window2`, `window3`.

PyGame can display only one window - so there is no sense to create 3 windows. You can draw all in one window.

If you want switch content in window then you could create 3 `Surface()`, and blit on these surfaces, and later you can blit different surface in different moment.

---

**EDIT:**

My version with fixes. I also used `pygame.time` instead of `threading.Timer` but it could use special `event` for this.

But I see one disadvance: it can't move back from window 3 to window 2. It would have to run both windows in one `while`-loop with `if nextWindow == 2:` and `if nextWindow == 3:`

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- 

w, h = 200, 300

pyX = 1280
pyY = 720

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

# --- functions ---

def draw_window1():
    window.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    window.blit(text1, textRect1)

def draw_window2():
    window.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    window.blit(beefSprite, rectBeef)
    window.blit(text2, textRect2)

def draw_window3():
    window.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    window.blit(text3, textRect3)

# --- main ---

# start the game
pygame.init()

# making the windows
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))

# set up the games name
pygame.display.set_caption("Ordering Simulator")

# Variables
nextWindow = 0

# sprites
beefSprite = pygame.image.load("Hamburger.png").convert_alpha()
rectBeef = beefSprite.get_rect()
rectBeef.center = window.get_rect().center

# Set up the text
font1 = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 64)
font2 = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)

# Text
text1 = font1.render("Welcome to Cesar's ordering sim", True, black, white)
text2 = font2.render("What would you like? We have beef, chicken and tofu sandwich.", True, white, black)
text3 = font2.render("So you have chosen.", True, white, black)

# icon
icon = pygame.image.load("cheeseburger.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# setup text pt2
textRect1 = text1.get_rect()
textRect2 = text2.get_rect()
textRect3 = text3.get_rect()
textRect1.center = (pyX // 2, pyY // 2)
textRect2.midtop = (pyX // 2, pyY - 600)
textRect3.midtop = (pyX // 2, pyY - 600)

# add a background
bg = pygame.image.load("restaurant.jpg")
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (1280, 720))

# loop for game window
running1 = True
running2 = True
running3 = True

# timer setup
current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
loop_end = current_time + 3000  # 3000ms

print('[DEBUG] first')

draw_window1()

while running1:

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    
    if current_time >= loop_end:
        nextWindow = nextWindow + 1
        running1 = False

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running1 = False
            running2 = False
            running3 = False
            
    pygame.display.update()

# Second screen which starts the game
print('[DEBUG] second')

draw_window2()

while running2:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            #running1 = False
            running2 = False
            running3 = False
            
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if rectBeef.collidepoint(event.pos):
                nextWindow = nextWindow + 1
                running2 = False
            
    pygame.display.update()

# third screen
print('[DEBUG] third')

draw_window3()

while running3:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            #running1 = False
            #running2 = False
            running3 = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            nextWindow = nextWindow + 1
            running3 = False
            
    pygame.display.update()

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()  # some systems need it to close window
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version with window 2 and window 3 in one `while`-loop - so you can go back from window 3 to window 2, and next go again to window 3 and again go back to window 2, etc.

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- 

w, h = 200, 300

pyX = 1280
pyY = 720

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

# --- functions ---

def draw_window1():
    window.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    window.blit(text1, textRect1)

def draw_window2():
    window.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    window.blit(beefSprite, rectBeef)
    window.blit(text2, textRect2)

def draw_window3():
    window.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    window.blit(text3, textRect3)
    window.blit(text3a, text3a_rect)
    window.blit(text3b, text3b_rect)

# --- main ---

# start the game
pygame.init()

# making the windows
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))

# set up the games name
pygame.display.set_caption("Ordering Simulator")

# Variables
nextWindow = 0

# sprites
beefSprite = pygame.image.load("Hamburger.png").convert_alpha()
rectBeef = beefSprite.get_rect()
rectBeef.center = window.get_rect().center

# Set up the text
font1 = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 64)
font2 = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)

# Text
text1 = font1.render("Welcome to Cesar's ordering sim", True, black, white)
text2 = font2.render("What would you like? We have beef, chicken and tofu sandwich.", True, white, black)
text3 = font2.render("So you have chosen.", True, white, black)

text3a = font2.render("BACK", True, white, black)
text3a_rect = text3a.get_rect(center=window.get_rect().center)
text3a_rect.x -= 200

text3b = font2.render("NEXT (EXIT)", True, white, black)
text3b_rect = text3b.get_rect(center=window.get_rect().center)
text3b_rect.x += 200

# icon
#icon = pygame.image.load("cheeseburger.png")
#pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# setup text pt2
textRect1 = text1.get_rect()
textRect2 = text2.get_rect()
textRect3 = text3.get_rect()
textRect1.center = (pyX // 2, pyY // 2)
textRect2.midtop = (pyX // 2, pyY - 600)
textRect3.midtop = (pyX // 2, pyY - 600)

# add a background
bg = pygame.image.load("restaurant.jpg")
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (1280, 720))

# loop for game window
running1 = True
running2 = True

# timer setup
current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
loop_end = current_time + 3000  # 3000ms

print('[DEBUG] first')

draw_window1()

while running1:

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    
    if current_time >= loop_end:
        nextWindow = nextWindow + 1
        running1 = False

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running1 = False
            running2 = False
            
    pygame.display.update()

# Second screen which starts the game
print('[DEBUG] second & third')

nextWindow = 2

while running2:

    if nextWindow == 2:
    
        draw_window2()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                #running1 = False
                running2 = False
                
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if rectBeef.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    nextWindow = nextWindow + 1


    elif nextWindow == 3:
        draw_window3()
    
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                #running1 = False
                running2 = False

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if text3a_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    nextWindow = nextWindow - 1
                if text3b_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    nextWindow = nextWindow + 1
                    running2 = False
        
    pygame.display.update()

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()  # some systems need it to close window
```